# How to reshape a 4D numpy array to 3D array

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, recurrent-neural-network

I have a pandas array that contains a list of list of lists i.e. 3 embedded lists
`row 1 = [[[10,23,...,25],[10,23,...,25],[10,23,...,25]]]`
The smallest sublist contains 3 lists and each list contains 601 values. The first level of sublists contains variable number of lists
e.g. row 1 has a shape of (22,601,3), row 2 has a shape of (19,601,3) etc.

When I convert the array to a numpy dataframe, I have a shape of the total length of rows in the array.
`array = df.values or df.to_numpy()`
The array has 100 rows
`array.shape = (100,)`

where each index would have the different lengths
e.g. `array[0].shape = (22,601,3)`
rows = 22

I would like to flatten/reshape the array where the number of rows would remain the same but the number of dimensions would change such that the shape would be
`array.shape = (100,rows*601,3)`

Basically like flattening the array such that it fits the dimensions and becomes a **3D array** which can be fed into a RNN model

Comment: If all 100 "rows" have shape (n,601,3) then you should be able to `concatenate` with `axis=0`, producing a (sum(n), 601,3) array.  I'm not sure if a `reshape(100,-1,3)` will work right or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try a small example:

```
In [235]: alist = [np.ones((n,10,3),int) for n in [22,10,3,21]]
In [236]: arr = np.array(alist, object)
In [237]: arr.shape
Out[237]: (4,)
In [238]: arr[0].shape
Out[238]: (22, 10, 3)
```

This `arr` should be like your array from the df.

Simple concatenate of the subarrays on the first axis is possible if the other dimensions all match (e.g. (10,3)

```
In [239]: np.concatenate(arr, axis=0).shape
Out[239]: (56, 10, 3)
In [240]: sum([22,10,3,21])
Out[240]: 56
```

Does it make sense to reshape this to (4,14,10,3)?  This sum is multiple of 4, but that isn't true in general.

Alternatively we could reshape the subarrays to 2d, and then concatenate:

```
In [241]: arr1 = [i.reshape(-1,3) for i in arr]
In [242]: np.concatenate(arr1, axis=0).shape
Out[242]: (560, 3)
In [243]: np.concatenate(arr1, axis=0).reshape(4,-1,3).shape
Out[243]: (4, 140, 3)        # (4, 14*10, 3)
```

This may be the same.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for your answer
The issue I have is that, I don't want the array to have an infinite number of rows like in the example where the 4 rows are transformed into a 56 row array.

I'm trying to feed the array into a RNN which requires a 3D input and I need a class for each of the input. 
***4 rows to 4 labels***
However, I want the input size to be able to change for each input similar to how RNNs can take in any number of words and classify an article. 
I want the model to take any number of lists/arrays as input and classify it based on the labels.

Comment: Then what does `(100,rows*601,3)` mean?  What's rows?  That's a 3d array shape.

Comment: Yes it is a 3D array shape